# Getting 401 error with filter() function on stream object using Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, jupyter, tweepy

Following is the code I am using in Jupyter Notebook to capture and analyze Twitter streaming data. I am getting 401 error though the `stream` object is created after authentication. The authentication credentials are correct and I am using `tweepy` for authorization. Any insights?

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
print(auth)

<tweepy.auth.OAuthHandler object at 0x0000022B8450B288>

class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def __init__(self, api=None):
        super(MyStreamListener, self).__init__()
        self.num_tweets = 0
        self.file = open("tweets.txt", "w")

    def on_status(self, status):
        tweet = status._json
        self.file.write( json.dumps(tweet) + '\n' )
        self.num_tweets += 1
        if self.num_tweets < 100:
            return True
        else:
            return False
        self.file.close()

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)

l = MyStreamListener()
print(l)

<__main__.MyStreamListener object at 0x0000022B844D9E48>

stream = tweepy.Stream(auth, l)
print(stream)

<tweepy.streaming.Stream object at 0x0000022B843A8188>

stream.filter(['clinton', 'trump', 'sanders', 'cruz'])

401
```

Answer (score 0):

A 401 Unauthorized error can occur due to multiple reasons when filtering realtime Tweets:

> HTTP authentication failed due to either:
>
> - Invalid basic auth credentials, or an invalid OAuth request.
> - Out-of-sync timestamp in your OAuth request (the response body will indicate this).
> - Too many incorrect passwords entered or other login rate limiting.

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/filter-realtime/guides/connecting#errorcodes